# EF - Class that called SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to get the class that called the SaveChanges() method in the EventHandler?

That's because I have an entity called Activity which can have it's status changed by some parts of the system and I need to log it and save in the database. In the log table I need to store the IDs of the entity that was updated or created and thus caused the activity status to change.

I think I can either do it or try the unmaintainable solution.
The unmaintainable solution would be to add some code to every part of the system that changes the activity status.

PS: I can't use database triggers..

Comment: The EventHandler normally takes a first parameters of `Object sender` which should be the caller?

Comment: @Belogix the sender object is generally a reference to the object which *raises* the event, not the one which *invokes* it.

Comment: @Belogix, the sender is the ObjectContext because I attach the event handler to the [SavingChanges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx) method, which is called after the SaveChanges() is called and before the data is updated in the database.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think trying to update another table as part of the `SaveChanges` is the correct approach here, you would be coupling your logging mechanism to that particular context - what if you wanted to disable logging or switch it out to use a different type of logging? i.e. local file.

I would update the log table along with the entity itself if the update was successful i.e.

```
var entity = ...
// update entity
if (context.SaveChanges() != 0)
{
    // update log table
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible (but I would recommend against it) using the StackTrace, eg:

```
public class Test
{
    public event EventHandler AnEvent;

    public Test()
    {
        AnEvent += WhoDoneIt;
    }

    public void Trigger()
    {
        if (AnEvent != null)
            AnEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void WhoDoneIt(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var stack = new StackTrace();
        for (var i = 0; i < stack.FrameCount; i++)
        {
            var frame = stack.GetFrame(i);
            var method = frame.GetMethod();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}.{2}", i, method.DeclaringType.FullName, method.Name);
        }
    }    
}

public class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Test();
        test.Trigger();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If you look at the output of the program you can figure out which stack frame you want to look at and analyze the caller based on the Method of that frame.

HOWEVER, this can have serious performance implications - the stack trace is quite an expensive object to create, so I would really recommend changing your code to keep track of the caller in a different way -  one idea could be to store the caller in a threadstatic variable before calling SaveChanges and then clearing it out afterwards

Comment: If the logged information needs to be accurate, this also means the program needs to be compiled without optimisations, does it not?

Comment: Good point - but as long as the calling method isn't trivial (which it might be) then it shouldn't be inlined

Answer (score 1):

From your post it sounds like you're more interested in which entities are updating rather than which method called SaveChanges.

If that's the case, you can examine the pending changes and see which entities are either added or modified (or deleted if you care) and do your logging based on that information.

You would do that like this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    if (changeSet != null)
        foreach (var dbEntityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {

            switch (dbEntityEntry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    // log your data
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    // log your data
                    break;
            }
        }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: That's what I think is the best solution. I can check if the activity entity has a modified state and then check for other entities that also have this modified state and then save it.
I'm going to try it and then I give you feedback.